# Jupyter IntelliSense not working for Rust & evcxr

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, jupyter-notebook, intellisense

Trying out [evcxr_jupyter](https://github.com/google/evcxr/blob/main/evcxr_jupyter/README.md) with VS Code Jupyter extension & interactive window.

Code executes fine, but there are no code suggestions.

[image: rust intellisense example]

For python code, suggestions work fine.

[image: python intellisense example]

Is there some configuration, that can enable it for Rust as well? Or is it just not supported for now?